# Selecting Unique Element Only Once in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I am trying to write an XSLT (version 1.0) that selects a unique element only once. The situation is that I am calling an ESB and getting back a SOAP XML result. I transform that result to strip out a bunch of unused elements and attributes and end up with something like this:

```
<feed xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:sd="http://ice.exploration.nasa.gov/supplementalData">
<id>uuid:6875e533-7751-446b-9ece-57d414447dd9</id>
<totalResults>8</totalResults>
<startIndex>1</startIndex>
<itemsPerPage>50</itemsPerPage>
<entry>
  <system>Windchill</system>
  <type>NASAModelingandSimulationDocument</type>
  <shortId>297</shortId>
  <eid>uuid:3a26f040-01b1-4b0d-944d-f2c8bd874307</eid>
  <displayName>fedsearchtest NASA Modeling  and Simulation Document-PLM-0000001503(--1)</displayName>
  <url>https://nasa-icedev.nasa.gov/services/feeds/ice/bie/297</url>
  <name>fedsearchtest NASA Modeling  and Simulation Document</name>
  <version>--1</version>
  <description/>
  <creator>Pline, Alex</creator>
  <creationDateTime>2013-12-20T13:39:53-00:00</creationDateTime>
  <comment/>
  <identifier>PLM-0000001503</identifier>
  <modifier>Pline, Alex</modifier>
  <parentContainer>
     <Description>
        <type>Project</type>
        <shortId>123</shortId>
        <eid>uuid:9ca15ace-cfdb-4715-acc1-11f948aea997</eid>
        <displayName>Portal Development</displayName>
        <url>https://nasa-icedev.nasa.gov/services/feeds/ice/bie/123</url>
        <name>Portal Development</name>
        <version/>
        <description>Project</description>
        <creator/>
        <creationDateTime/>
        <comment/>
     </Description>
  </parentContainer>
  <state>INWORK</state>
  <status>c/i</status>
  <updateDateTime>2013-12-20T13:39:53-00:00</updateDateTime>
  <Document>
     <detailsURL>https://icedev.ndc.nasa.gov/Windchill/app/#ptc1/tcomp/infoPage?oid=VR:wt.doc.WTDocument:418523</detailsURL>
     <sbuCui>NULL</sbuCui>
     <exportControlEar>NULL</exportControlEar>
     <exportControlItar>NULL</exportControlItar>
     <NASADocument>
        <author/>
        <bookManager/>
        <cageCode/>
        <category/>
        <cmControlLevel>Not Applicable</cmControlLevel>
        <comments/>
        <controlAuthority/>
        <coverDate>2011-03-18 00:00:00 CDT</coverDate>
        <dataType>Not a Deliverable</dataType>
        <drdNumber/>
        <legacyDes/>
        <opr>Not Applicable</opr>
        <oprOrgCode/>
        <owningCenter/>
        <owningProject/>
        <record>false</record>
        <recordAfsNumber/>
        <recordCutOffDate/>
        <recordLocation/>
        <recordRetentionInstructions/>
        <recordSchedule/>
        <recordStatus/>
        <recordType/>
        <releaseDate/>
        <remotelyReleased>No</remotelyReleased>
        <subcategory/>
        <wbsNumber/>
        <NASAModelingandSimulationDocument>
           <credibilityLevel/>
           <criticalityLevel/>
           <developmentStatus>Not Applicable</developmentStatus>
           <externalUrl/>
           <fileFormat>Other</fileFormat>
           <fileFormatOther/>
           <issueTrackingUrl/>
           <modelSimToolAbbr/>
           <modelSimToolName/>
           <modelSimToolType/>
           <modelSimToolTypeOther/>
           <modelVersion/>
           <operatingSystems/>
           <otherAnalysisEfforts/>
           <pedigree/>
           <pocEmail/>
           <pocName/>
           <pocOrganization/>
           <pocPhone/>
           <programmingLanguage/>
           <proprietaryInformation/>
           <softwareClassification/>
           <tdsNumber/>
           <vvLevel/>
        </NASAModelingandSimulationDocument>
     </NASADocument>
     <files>
        <Bag>
           <Description>
              <type>File</type>
              <shortId/>
              <eid/>
              <displayName>Excel Document copy.xlsx</displayName>
              <url/>
              <name>Excel Document copy.xlsx</name>
              <version>2</version>
              <description/>
              <creator>Pline, Alex</creator>
              <creationDateTime>2013-12-20 13:39:53 CST</creationDateTime>
              <modifier>Pline, Alex</modifier>
              <parentContainer/>
              <updateDateTime>2013-12-20 14:02:40 CST</updateDateTime>
              <checksum>0</checksum>
              <downloadUrl>https://icedev.ndc.nasa.gov/Windchill/servlet/WindchillAuthGW/wt.content.ContentHttp/viewContent/Excel%20Document%20copy.xlsx?u8&amp;HttpOperationItem=wt.content.ApplicationData%3A418541&amp;ContentHolder=wt.doc.WTDocument%3A418524&amp;originalFileName=Excel+Document+copy.xlsx&amp;forceDownload=true</downloadUrl>
              <fileSize>26,416</fileSize>
              <format>xlsx</format>
              <role>PRIMARY</role>
           </Description>
        </Bag>
     </files>
     <parentFolder>
        <Description>
           <type>Folder</type>
           <shortId>125</shortId>
           <eid>uuid:76904fcc-338f-4f3e-a1c6-46c7de7d0a5a</eid>
           <displayName>Federated Search Test</displayName>
           <url>https://nasa-icedev.nasa.gov/services/feeds/ice/bie/125</url>
           <name>Federated Search Test</name>
           <version/>
           <description>Folder</description>
           <creator/>
           <creationDateTime/>
           <comment/>
        </Description>
     </parentFolder>
     <references/>
     <referencedBy/>
     <uses/>
     <usedBy/>
  </Document>
</entry>
<entry>
  <system>Liferay</system>
  <type>Part</type>
  <shortId>3105</shortId>
  <eid>uuid:9b080a96-5425-43fd-a3cb-3bca2cd073b6</eid>
  <displayName>fedsearchtest Part-0000000121(A-1)</displayName>
  <url>https://nasa-icedev.nasa.gov/services/feeds/ice/bie/3105</url>
  <name>fedsearchtest Part</name>
  <version>A-1</version>
  <description/>
  <creator>Pline, Alex</creator>
  <creationDateTime>2013-12-13T13:14:57-00:00</creationDateTime>
  <comment/>
  <identifier>0000000121</identifier>
  <modifier>Pline, Alex</modifier>
  <parentContainer>
     <Description>
        <type>Project</type>
        <shortId>123</shortId>
        <eid>uuid:9ca15ace-cfdb-4715-acc1-11f948aea997</eid>
        <displayName>Portal Development</displayName>
        <url>https://nasa-icedev.nasa.gov/services/feeds/ice/bie/123</url>
        <name>Portal Development</name>
        <version/>
        <description>Project</description>
        <creator/>
        <creationDateTime/>
        <comment/>
     </Description>
  </parentContainer>
  <state>INWORK</state>
  <status>c/i</status>
  <updateDateTime>2013-12-13T13:14:57-00:00</updateDateTime>
  <Part>
     <detailsURL>https://icedev.ndc.nasa.gov/Windchill/app/#ptc1/tcomp/infoPage?oid=VR:wt.part.WTPart:417193</detailsURL>
     <sbuCui>NULL</sbuCui>
     <exportControlEar>NULL</exportControlEar>
     <exportControlItar>NULL</exportControlItar>
     <alternateIdentifier/>
     <assemblyMode>separable</assemblyMode>
     <bomType/>
     <classification/>
     <classificationOrganization/>
     <classificationReason/>
     <classifiedBy/>
     <contractNumber/>
     <contributor/>
     <coverage/>
     <date/>
     <dateApplied/>
     <defaultTraceCode>0</defaultTraceCode>
     <defaultUnit>ea</defaultUnit>
     <endItem>false</endItem>
     <findNumber/>
     <jobAuthorizationNumber/>
     <maximumAllowed/>
     <minimumRequired/>
     <ownedBy/>
     <owner/>
     <phantomPart>false</phantomPart>
     <phase/>
     <publisher/>
     <quantity/>
     <referenceDesignator/>
     <relation/>
     <representation/>
     <rights/>
     <source>make</source>
     <subject/>
     <supplierId/>
     <unit/>
     <files/>
     <parentFolder>
        <Description>
           <type/>
           <shortId>3029</shortId>
           <eid>uuid:eb7590ed-53fd-4669-9be9-e190b02d7bb6</eid>
           <displayName>Federated Search Test</displayName>
           <url>https://nasa-icedev.nasa.gov/services/feeds/ice/bie/3029</url>
           <name>Federated Search Test</name>
           <version/>
           <description>Folder</description>
           <creator/>
           <creationDateTime/>
           <comment/>
        </Description>
     </parentFolder>
     <describes/>
     <describedBy/>
     <referencedBy/>
     <references/>
     <usedBy/>
     <uses/>
  </Part>
</entry>
<entry>
  <system>Liferay</system>
  <type>Part</type>
  <shortId>3107</shortId>
  <eid>uuid:a828443a-5b8f-4ff7-a72f-39b9aef0f12f</eid>
  <displayName>fedsearchtest NASA Part-0000000122(1-1)</displayName>
  <url>https://nasa-icedev.nasa.gov/services/feeds/ice/bie/3107</url>
  <name>fedsearchtest NASA Part</name>
  <version>1-1</version>
  <description/>
  <creator>Pline, Alex</creator>
  <creationDateTime>2013-12-13T13:15:19-00:00</creationDateTime>
  <comment/>
  <identifier>0000000122</identifier>
  <modifier>Pline, Alex</modifier>
  <parentContainer>
     <Description>
        <type>Project</type>
        <shortId>123</shortId>
        <eid>uuid:9ca15ace-cfdb-4715-acc1-11f948aea997</eid>
        <displayName>Portal Development</displayName>
        <url>https://nasa-icedev.nasa.gov/services/feeds/ice/bie/123</url>
        <name>Portal Development</name>
        <version/>
        <description>Project</description>
        <creator/>
        <creationDateTime/>
        <comment/>
     </Description>
  </parentContainer>
  <state>INWORK</state>
  <status>c/i</status>
  <updateDateTime>2013-12-13T13:15:19-00:00</updateDateTime>
  <Part>
     <detailsURL>https://icedev.ndc.nasa.gov/Windchill/app/#ptc1/tcomp/infoPage?oid=VR:wt.part.WTPart:417404</detailsURL>
     <sbuCui>NULL</sbuCui>
     <exportControlEar>NULL</exportControlEar>
     <exportControlItar>NULL</exportControlItar>
     <alternateIdentifier/>
     <assemblyMode>separable</assemblyMode>
     <bomType/>
     <classification/>
     <classificationOrganization/>
     <classificationReason/>
     <classifiedBy/>
     <contractNumber/>
     <contributor/>
     <coverage/>
     <date/>
     <dateApplied/>
     <defaultTraceCode>0</defaultTraceCode>
     <defaultUnit>ea</defaultUnit>
     <endItem>false</endItem>
     <findNumber/>
     <jobAuthorizationNumber/>
     <maximumAllowed/>
     <minimumRequired/>
     <ownedBy/>
     <owner/>
     <phantomPart>false</phantomPart>
     <phase/>
     <publisher/>
     <quantity/>
     <referenceDesignator/>
     <relation/>
     <representation/>
     <rights/>
     <source>make</source>
     <subject/>
     <supplierId/>
     <unit/>
     <files/>
     <parentFolder>
        <Description>
           <type/>
           <shortId>3029</shortId>
           <eid>uuid:eb7590ed-53fd-4669-9be9-e190b02d7bb6</eid>
           <displayName>Federated Search Test</displayName>
           <url>https://nasa-icedev.nasa.gov/services/feeds/ice/bie/3029</url>
           <name>Federated Search Test</name>
           <version/>
           <description>Folder</description>
           <creator/>
           <creationDateTime/>
           <comment/>
        </Description>
     </parentFolder>
     <describes/>
     <describedBy/>
     <referencedBy/>
     <references/>
     <usedBy/>
     <uses/>
  </Part>
</entry>
<entry>
  <system>Liferay</system>
  <type>Part</type>
  <shortId>3109</shortId>
  <eid>uuid:9e47aa11-4328-4712-89dd-6277c789746d</eid>
  <displayName>fedsearchtest End Item-0000000123(A-1)</displayName>
  <url>https://nasa-icedev.nasa.gov/services/feeds/ice/bie/3109</url>
  <name>fedsearchtest End Item</name>
  <version>A-1</version>
  <description/>
  <creator>Pline, Alex</creator>
  <creationDateTime>2013-12-13T13:15:52-00:00</creationDateTime>
  <comment/>
  <identifier>0000000123</identifier>
  <modifier>Pline, Alex</modifier>
  <parentContainer>
     <Description>
        <type>Project</type>
        <shortId>123</shortId>
        <eid>uuid:9ca15ace-cfdb-4715-acc1-11f948aea997</eid>
        <displayName>Portal Development</displayName>
        <url>https://nasa-icedev.nasa.gov/services/feeds/ice/bie/123</url>
        <name>Portal Development</name>
        <version/>
        <description>Project</description>
        <creator/>
        <creationDateTime/>
        <comment/>
     </Description>
  </parentContainer>
  <state>INWORK</state>
  <status>c/i</status>
  <updateDateTime>2013-12-13T13:15:52-00:00</updateDateTime>
  <Part>
     <detailsURL>https://icedev.ndc.nasa.gov/Windchill/app/#ptc1/tcomp/infoPage?oid=VR:wt.part.WTPart:417427</detailsURL>
     <sbuCui>NULL</sbuCui>
     <exportControlEar>NULL</exportControlEar>
     <exportControlItar>NULL</exportControlItar>
     <alternateIdentifier/>
     <assemblyMode>separable</assemblyMode>
     <bomType/>
     <classification/>
     <classificationOrganization/>
     <classificationReason/>
     <classifiedBy/>
     <contractNumber/>
     <contributor/>
     <coverage/>
     <date/>
     <dateApplied/>
     <defaultTraceCode>S</defaultTraceCode>
     <defaultUnit>ea</defaultUnit>
     <endItem>true</endItem>
     <findNumber/>
     <jobAuthorizationNumber/>
     <maximumAllowed/>
     <minimumRequired/>
     <ownedBy/>
     <owner/>
     <phantomPart>false</phantomPart>
     <phase/>
     <publisher/>
     <quantity/>
     <referenceDesignator/>
     <relation/>
     <representation/>
     <rights/>
     <source>make</source>
     <subject/>
     <supplierId/>
     <unit/>
     <files/>
     <parentFolder>
        <Description>
           <type/>
           <shortId>3029</shortId>
           <eid>uuid:eb7590ed-53fd-4669-9be9-e190b02d7bb6</eid>
           <displayName>Federated Search Test</displayName>
           <url>https://nasa-icedev.nasa.gov/services/feeds/ice/bie/3029</url>
           <name>Federated Search Test</name>
           <version/>
           <description>Folder</description>
           <creator/>
           <creationDateTime/>
           <comment/>
        </Description>
     </parentFolder>
     <describes/>
     <describedBy/>
     <referencedBy/>
     <references/>
     <usedBy/>
     <uses/>
  </Part>
</entry>
</feed>
```

Note that other entry elements can have other child elements, depending on their type.

What I would like for the XSLT to do is create a single entry with all possible elements under it that exist in the entry elements in the source document. So, in the case of the above XML, the output entry would look something like this:

```
<entry>
  <system>Windchill</system>
  <type>Document</type>
  <shortId>298</shortId>
  <parentContainer>
    ..
  </parentContainer>
  <Document>
    <NASADocument>
      ..
      <NASAModelingandSimulationDocument>
        ..
      </NASAModelingandSimulationDocument>
    </NASADocument>
    <files>
      ..
    </files>
    <parentFolder>
      ..
    </parentFolder>
  </Document>
  <Part>
    ..
  </Part>
</entry>
```

Essentially, I am trying to create a single entry record that has all of the potential fields that an entry record can have. The values of those fields do not really matter, as I am building this result to populate a UI element from which the user can choose the fields they would like to display.

I am sure there is some way to approach this using keys, but I cannot figure it out for the life of me. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I don't understand you question. Your input has four distinct entries, each with its own child elements. By what logic did you reduce this to only one entry at the output? Or are you only trying to "map" the input? If so, why do some of the elements contain data and others do not?

Comment: I need the output to be a single entry with only one instance of each possible field in all of the input entries. The output is supposed to be a single entry record with all of the fields that are possible to exist in an entry record in it.

Answer (score 0):

This could be relatively simple or very complex or anywhere in between - all depending on what assumptions can be made regarding the uniqueness of the element names.

Let me start with what I think is the simplest case, where we can assume that each element name is unique to its level in the document hierarchy. In the following example:

```
<root>
    <top id="1">
        <middle/>
    </top>
    <top id="2">
        <middle>
            <low/>
        </middle>
    </top>
    <top id="3">
        <middle>
            <bottom/>
        </middle>
    </top>
    <top id="4">
        <middle>
            <bottom>
                <rock/>
            </bottom>
        </middle>
    </top>
</root>
```

Here we assume that `<top>` can appear **only** as a child of `<root>`, `<middle>` is **always** a child of `<top>` (or of a sibling of `<top>`), and so on. Under this assumption, we can "map" the above structure relatively easily by:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="sameName" match="*" use="local-name()" />

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('sameName', local-name())/*[count(. | key('sameName', local-name())[1]) = 1]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to produce:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <top>
    <middle>
      <low/>
      <bottom>
        <rock/>
      </bottom>
    </middle>
  </top>
</root>
```

If the above assumption cannot be maintained, then things get more complicated. If, for example, each level can have its own `<description>` element, then you will need to add more constraints to the uniqueness test. For example, you could test for the uniqueness of the element's name concatenated with its parent's name. Or you could add the count of the element's ancestors to the mix.

Ultimately, to do this without *any* assumptions at all, you would need to look at the entire path to the element. This needs to collected recursively - so you would need to make a preliminary processing pass before you could start selecting the unique elements only.

Comment: Thanks Michael. This gets me pretty close. However, unfortunately, there are elements of the same name that are used under different child elements, such as "shortId", "eid", "type", "name", "version", "displayName", "url", "creationDateTime", "updateDateTime", "description" and "comment". Those elements appear directly under an "entry" element and also under the child "entry" elements of "parentContainer/Description", "files/Bag/Description", and "parentFolder/Description".

Comment: @NathanShaw So, you have tried to implement one of the two suggestions I have made for this eventuality and ... ?

Comment: Turns out the ESB has services available to get the data structure of the object types, so we will be able to just call those services to get the data fields for the object types in the response.